# Method for getting the DataTable when having connection ID and the SQL command

Tags: c#, beginner, asp.net, .net-datatable

I am quite new to C# and to the ASP.NET programming. When maintaining the legacy code, I have found rather terrible implementation of the method that is used on many places to get the `DataTable` object with the data filled by the SQL command.

Here is my first approach to rewrite it. Does `using` work with the `return` as shown below? Should the `da` and `ds` be released explicitly somehow? If `ds` is released, is the returned `DataTable` reference counted so that it will not be deleted?

```
public DataTable getdata2(string connection_string_id, string sqlcmd)
{
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings[connection_string_id].ConnectionString;

    // Open the connection and return the first table.
    // A single one should be there, only.
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Debug.Assert(ds.Tables.Count == 1);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos) already stated it is ok to return out of an using block.

### Naming

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), method names should be named using `PascalCase` casing. So `getData2` should become `GetData2` which should be still renamed to a more meaningful name.
Also input parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing, so `connection_string_id` should become `connectionStringId`.

If you are sure, that there will only be 1 table, you can also use the overloaded `Fill()` method which takes a `DataTable` as input parameter.
You could also stack the usings, but this is a matter of taste.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd, con))
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable ;
}
```

In my opinion, your code does a little bit to much.

1. Retrieving the `ConnectionString`
2. Query the database

So let us add a method to retrieve the `ConnectionString`, which is then passed to the `Getdata2()` method.

```
private String GetConnectionString(String connectionStringId)
{
    return ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings[connectionStringId].ConnectionString;
}
```

---

```
public DataTable GetData2(String connectionString, String sqlCommand)
{

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, connection))
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable ;
    }
}
```

To answer when to use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx): use it if the related object implements the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.

Comment: Thanks. Is the `con.Open()` necessary or will it be done by the adapter anyway? Concerning the `connectionStringId`, the application actually uses only two connection strings. I was already thinking about making the connection object the class members and avoid the first argument at all. But I have to be slow with C# as I do not know it that much.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zxkb3c3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it isn't needed. If the connection is closed, it will be opened

Comment: Thanks for the info about `con.Open()` -- I did not noticed that in the doc at first (`IDbConnection`). So basically, if I want to reuse the open connection, I should pass the open connection object. Otherwise, leaving the `con.Open()` out makes the code one line shorter. Am I right?

Comment: See: [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/142068](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/142068)

Comment: Thanks again! I am going to write a `DbUtil` class with the knowledge obtained here. Then I will post it for review and will place the link here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's ok to return from the middle of a `using` block. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369887/are-there-any-side-effects-of-returning-from-inside-a-using-statement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662773/returning-in-the-middle-of-a-using-block) related discussions.

No need to release the `DataSet`, but you should wrap the `SqlDataAdapter` in `using`, something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd, con))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        Debug.Assert(ds.Tables.Count == 1);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: When the `using` should be used and when not? For example, here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx the `using` is used only for the connection and not for the adapter. What would happen to `ds` after the enclosing brace (say the return was not there)? Also, is the `con.Open();` necessary?

Comment: It looks like Heslacher answered to those questions already. I have nothing to add.